# Why does a charger charges one phone but not another?

Tags: charging

I have a charger that came with my phone, Huawei Mate 9. I recently bought another phone, Xiaomi Pocophone X1. I tried to charge the new phone with my charger (and cable) and it went into boot loops and ended up draining the battery instead of charging. I then connected it to the charger that came with it and it charged fine.

What caused this difference? I'm asking since I want to buy a backup charger and want to know what to look for (other than buying a Xiaomi original)

Comment: Strange, I would think that the Xiaomi would just go into slow charging with a non-OEM cable unless both Huawei and Xiaomi uses a similar but different protocol for each of their proprietary fast charging solutions.

Comment: To add to @MorrisonChang comment, both of them (OEMs) do not share the slightest hint about their proprietary technologies. In theory, what you faced shouldn't happen but since it did, you are better off buying a spare charger from them, rather than bother with reasons in my opinion